# Finding and proving limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Find the limits and use the definition of limit to justify that you found the right limit

> $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2+3\sin x^4}{5+6x^{1/7}}$$

I got that the limit is $0$.

I am not sure how to prove, by the definition of a limit that...

$$\frac{2+3\sin x^4}{5+6x^{1/7}} - 0 <\epsilon$$

Also looking to find the same for

$$ \lim{x to \infty} \frac{2x^3-4x+1}{5x^3+6n+7} $$

Comment: Use squeeze theorem.  $-1\le \sin x^4 \le 1$ so $ \frac {-1}{5 + 6x^{\frac 17}}=\frac{2+3\sin x^4}{5+6x^{1/7}} \le \frac {5}{5 + 6x^{\frac 17}}$ and as $\lim \frac {-1}{5 + 6x^{\frac 17}} = \lim \frac {5}{5 + 6x^{\frac 17}}= 0$ we are done

Answer (score 1):

As a more effective method, note that since $-1\le\sin x^4\le 1$

$$\frac{2-3}{5+6x^{1/7}}\le\frac{2+3\sin x^4}{5+6x^{1/7}}\le\frac{2+3}{5+6x^{1/7}}$$

then refer to [**squeeze theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

By the formal definition we need to prove that for any $\epsilon>0 \quad \exists x_0$ such that $\forall x> x_0 \quad $$\left|\frac{2+3\sin x^4}{5+6x^{1/7}}\right|<\epsilon $, therefore

$$\left|\frac{2+3\sin x^4}{5+6x^{1/7}}\right|<\left|\frac{5}{5+6x^{1/7}}\right|<\epsilon \implies 6\epsilon x^{1/7}>5-5\epsilon \implies x>x_0=\left(\frac{5-5\epsilon}{6\epsilon}\right)^7$$

Comment: thanks! This is how I arrived upon evaluating the limit originally. I am stuck on figuring out how to prove it via the formal definition of a limit/convergent sequence

Comment: @kmediate Ah ok, I add that.

Comment: @kmediate Well, it's worth knowing how to prove the Squeeze theorem.

Comment: looks great! How might approach the formal proof of the second limit?

Comment: @kmediate You shuold ask a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

$|\frac{2+3\sin x^4}{5+6x^{1/7}} - 0|<\epsilon \Leftarrow$

$-\epsilon < \frac{2+3\sin x^4}{5+6x^{1/7}} < \epsilon \Leftarrow$

$-\epsilon < \frac {-1}{5+6x^{\frac 17}} < \frac {5}{5+6x^{\frac 17}} <\epsilon \Leftarrow$

$-\epsilon < \frac {-5}{5+6x^{\frac 17}} < \frac {5}{5+6x^{\frac 17}} <\epsilon \Leftarrow$

$| \frac {5}{5+6x^{\frac 17}}|< \epsilon \Leftarrow$

$\frac 5{\epsilon} < 5+6x^{\frac 17} \Leftarrow$

$\frac {\frac 5{\epsilon} - 6}5 < x^{\frac 17} \Leftarrow$

$(\frac {\frac 5{\epsilon} - 6}5)^6 < x$

So for any $\epsilon > 0$ if $x > N = (\frac {\frac 5{\epsilon} - 6}5)^6$ we have $|\frac{2+3\sin x^4}{5+6x^{1/7}} - 0|<\epsilon$.

....

Note: this implies the Squeeze Theorem on the third line.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Limit Laws:

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow a} \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \dfrac{ \lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)}{\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x)}$$ if $$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x) \ne 0$$

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{2+3\sin x^4}{5+6x^{1/7}} = \dfrac{\lim_{x \to \infty} {2+3\sin x^4}}{\lim_{x \to \infty} 5+6x^{1/7}}$$

The rest is easy...